# Formal version of "one off"

Tags: formality, colloquialisms

In an academic paper, while describing an organization being not the only example of its kind, I used a sentence like:
This organization was not a one-off. 
However, I feel like it sounds too colloquial. Is there a better, more formal way to say it?
Thank you...

Comment: It would help for you to describe the sense in which *one-off* (or its substitute) is to be applied. For example, if it was '*spin-offs from a parent company*', you might say "This organisation was not the only subsidiary/etc", whereas if it was '*company that earned a lot of money*' you might say "This organisation was not the only success story".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unique](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique) would seem to fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

[Outlier](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outlier) may fit the context better:

"The organization was not an outlier"

Answer (score -1):

What about "Organizaion XYZ is no freak of nature/chance; there are many more that belong to its tribe" or "Organization XYZ is only one exemplar of its type; there are many companies kindred to it"? I think this really depends on the context - you will have to decide whether it suits the discipline - social science, or management or other such .

Comment: Why the downvotes? Please explain.

Comment: *Freak of Nature* is at least as colloquial as *One Off*.  Probably not the best choice for an academic paper.